# Passing additional parameters to fmincon

Tags: matlab, constraints, curve-fitting, data-fitting

I want to fit two parameters on an equation using `fmincon`. I did that with `lsqnonlin` but I want to take advantage of the inequality constraints of `fmincon`.

The problem is that I can not pass the two vectors of the measured data, e.g. `y(x)`, into the function in the same way I did it in `lsqnonlin`.

How should I do this?

```
estim = lsqnonlin(@fit_simp,X0,lb,ub,options,X,Y) %X,Y are the measured data in vectors, y(x)

estim = fmincon(@fit_simp,X0,[],[],[],[],[],[],nonlcon,options);
```

how will I pass the measured vectors?

Comment: So, you have measured data and want to fit a known model to it? What are the inequality constraints you want obeyed then, what do they represent?

Comment: Probably with an anonymous function - can you post your code used on lsqnonlin

Comment: Yes, I do have measured data such as y(x). My problem is not how to define the constraints but how to feed fmincon with the measured data [vectors].

Comment: @user2010599: I asked because it sounds like an [XY problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341); perhaps with more detail, we might see a way to avoid using `fmincon` altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an anonymous function like this:

```
estim = fmincon(@(y)fit_simp(y),X0,[],[],[],[],[],[],nonlcon,options);
```

Obviously you have to adjust your objective function to accept the parameters, i.e. `fit_simp` becomes `fit_simp(y)`

This is directly from the documentation, search for anonymous in this page:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html and also http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/pass-extra-parameters.html

I just saw in your code you want to pas in two extra parameters, X and Y. You might have to encapsulate these in a single variable for the anonymous function (but also maybe you can send both I'm not sure)

try

```
options.Y = Y;
options.X = X;
```

and then use `@(options)fit_simp(options)`

Comment: As I understood fmincon minimizes a function that returns a scalar, but fit_simp returns a vector.
That is the reason for the error. (Lsqnonlin was solving the same problem)

"User supplied objective function must return a scalar value."

Do you know how can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yeah, I suggest you start a new question where you show your objective function and describe the actual optimization / curve fitting and I'm sure it won't be too hard to transform it to output a scalar. It's usually just sum of square errors: scalar = sum((x - y).^2)

Comment: I think I solve the problem. The objective function was returning a vector and it should be a scalar, so I turned the objective functioon to return the sum(element*.element), that means the sum of the square of the elements of the vector.

Comment: is element a vector of X - Y? Also your code is the same as sum(element.^2) which might be easier to read. up to you.